# Showing distribution of a random variable

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

The following exercise is given:

Let $\Omega = \{(a_1, . . . , a_T ) : a_i ∈ \{−1, +1\},\ \forall i \in [T]\}$. For $p \in (0, 1)$ we define $\mathsf{P}(\{(a_1, . . . , a_T )\}) := p^k(1 − p)^{T−k}$, if $k = |{i : a_i = +1}|$

$(i)$ Show that $\sum_{\omega \in \Omega} \mathsf P(\{\omega\}) = 1$ and determine $|\Omega|$.

From $(i)$, with the natural extension $\mathsf P(A) := \sum_{\omega \in A} \mathsf P(\{\omega\})$, we find that $\mathsf P$ is a probability measure on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ with $\mathcal{F} := 2^{\Omega}$.

$(ii)$ Let $\xi_t(\omega) := a_t$, if $\omega = (a_1, . . . , a_T )$ and $1 \leq t \leq T$. Show that the sequence of random variables $\{ξ_t\}_{t=1}^{T}$ is an iid sequence on the space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathsf{P})$.

$(iii)$ Identify the distribution of the random variable $\xi_1 + · · · + \xi_t$.

I have already solved the first and second question of the exercise, so there is no need to worry about explaining the whole exercise to me. I have just written down the whole exercise for better understanding.

However, I have trouble about the third question since, to my shame, I have no idea how to approach a question like this. Could maybe somebody help me to get a better understanding of the third question and how to solve it appropriately?

Comment: Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Could you answer the question if $a_i \in  \{0, 1\}$ rather than $\{−1, +1\}$?

Comment: @EgorIvanov I think that we have to use the fact that all $\xi$s are iid, but I am struggling with the linearity of our "new" random variable $z = \xi_1 + \xi_2 + \ldots + \xi_t$. How can I solve that?

Comment: @Henry I am not sure, but I think in that case this would give me the binomial formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use probability-generating function (PGF):
$$\psi_{\xi_i}(z) = \mathsf E\left[z^{\xi_i}\right] =(1-p)z^{-1}+pz$$
You have already proven that $\{\xi_i\}_{i=1}^n$ are i.i.d. random variables, so
$$\psi_{\xi_1+\dots+\xi_n}(z) = \left(\psi_{\xi_1}(z)\right)^n=$$
$$=\left( (1-p)z^{-1}+pz \right)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}p^kz^k(1-p)^{n-k}z^{k-n} = $$
$$=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}z^{2k-n}$$
It means that $\xi=\xi_1+\dots+\xi_n$ has the following distribution:
$$\mathsf P\left\{\xi = 2k-n\right\} = \binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k} \: \forall  \:k=0,\dots,n$$
Such random variables are used to describe so called **random walk.**

Comment: Could you maybe explain to me the relation between the PGF and the distribution in general? You have just concluded that the coefficients of this sum is the distribution of the random variable but I would like to better understand that.

Comment: @MathGeek Perhaps it would be better to check [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability-generating_function), because it is quite hard to explain in comments

Comment: Ok thank you. So, to put it casually (in my own words), the answer was practically already given in the first question, since we can use the same probability for the case $k = |i: a_i = -1|$. Now we just have to think about the amount of possibilities, such that the sum of those $\xi$s attains the value $2k-n$ (notice that we always jump by two if one of the $\xi$s changes) and that is $n \choose k$. Did I get that right based on your very good answer?

Comment: @MathGeek Yes, exactly :) PGF and other functions in probability theory were invented to formalise ideas of this type